# Faster way to collect data from JSON than looping in spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am learning Javascript and this is my first time working with Google Sheets Apps Script. What I am doing is taking a large JSON file and importing it into my sheet. After that I am populating a few hundred properties based on the key:value found in the JSON.

This is how it kinda works right now:

1. Go to first column and first row of my sheet.
2. Get the name (property name).
3. Search the JSON for the key and then grab the value.
4. Update a neighbor cell with the value found in the JSON.

Right now it all works the only issue is it seems to be pretty slow. It takes about .5-1 second per lookup and when I have 200+ properties it just seems slow. This might just be a limitation or it might be my logic.

My sheet can be found here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tt3eh1RjL_CbUIaPzj10DbocgyDC0iNRIba2B4YTGgg/edit#gid=0

My function that does everything:

```
function parse() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1);

  var range1 = sheet.getRange("A2");
  var cell = range.getCell(1, 1);

  var event_line = cell.getValue();
  
  var tmp = event_line.split(". ");

  var col_number = tmp[0];
  var event_name = tmp[1];

  event_json = get_json_from_cell(col_number);

  const obj = JSON.parse(event_json);
  var traits = obj.context.traits;
  var properties = obj.properties;



  //Get the range for the section where properties are

  var traits_range = sheet.getRange("contextTraits");
  var allprop = sheet.getRange("testAll");

  var alllen = allprop.getNumRows();

  var length = traits_range.getNumRows();
  
  for (var i = 1; i < length; i++) {
    var cell = traits_range.getCell(i, 1);
    var req = traits_range.getCell(i, 4).getValue();
    var trait = cell.getValue();
    var result = traits[trait];
    var result_cell = traits_range.getCell(i, 3);

    if (result == undefined) {
      if (req == "y"){
        result = "MISSING REQ";
        result_cell.setBackground("red");
      } else {
        result = "MISSING";
        result_cell.setBackground("green");
      }
    } else {
      result_cell.setBackground("blue");
    }
    result_cell.setValue(result);
    Logger.log(result);    
  }

  for (var i = 1; i < alllen; i++) {
    var cell = allprop.getCell(i,1);
    var req = allprop.getCell(i, 4).getValue();
    var prop = cell.getValue();
    var result = properties[prop];
    var result_cell = allprop.getCell(i, 3);

    if (result == undefined) {
      if (req == "y"){
        result = "MISSING REQ";
        result_cell.setBackground("red");
      } else {
        result = "MISSING";
        result_cell.setBackground("green");
      }
    } else {
      result_cell.setBackground("blue");
    }
    result_cell.setValue(result);
  }
  Logger.log(result);


}
```

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: undefined `get_json_from_cell(col_number)`

Comment: What was the reason for placing JSON in the spreadsheet in the first place?

Comment: You can flatten the JSON and hold property names and their values in a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for example. Then lookup the value for a given property whenever you need it. This way you only need to iterate through the JSON once and can lookup the values in constant time (`O(1)`).

Comment: @Mushroomator I found some documentation related to my issue. The slow down is caused from the call to ```getValue()``` in the loop. I replaced it with calling ```getValues()``` function outside of the loop and it is instant now.

Comment: getting values from individually referenced cells (as you have done in your`i` loops) is very slow and almost certainly a major factor in your problem. Instead, load the whole chunk of relevant data into a 2d array using e.g. `;getRange(1,1,218,1).getValues()` to load all of the data in column A into the array. Note, although a single column, it's still a 2d array, each 'row' being an array holding a single value. Your array will be contaminated with non-property values so you'll need to skip some but looping/accessing that array will be very fast compared to referencing cells.

Comment: @soqq it looks like you found your problem while I was commenting. The array of values is the way to go.

Comment: It will be great if you add the answer that you found so other people can learn about the issue that you found in your code [@soqq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19907315/soqq)